# HTML wrapper for auto updating

Tags: html, refresh, wrapper

How do I create an html wrapper that auto updates an existing web page that I can't edit?
On my site we have a web based image viewer that has a 30 minute limit before users are logged out automatically.
I have no acces to the web page for editing purposes. Is it possible to make a script that keeps refreshing the web page  so it won't log out?
Best regards Mads - Copenhagen, Denmark.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that - you may want to use JavaScript.